# What does it mean + to-infinitive / gerund

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I always come across with this form "What does it mean+ ***to-infinitive***" . But I don't understand why we use **to-infinitive** instead of **gerund** after **mean**. As far as I know, mean + **to-infinitive** means "intend".

> 1. What does it mean ***to be*** human?
> 2. What does it mean ***being*** human?
> 3. What does it mean ***to be*** an American?
> 4. What does it mean ***being*** an American?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In questions 1 to 4, "to be/being human/an American" is the subject of the sentence and does not form a pattern with the verb "mean". Proof of this is that in the affirmative form both the infinitive and the gerund will appear at the beginning of the sentence, not after "mean":

- **To be** human/an American **means** ...
- **Being** human/an American **means** ...

"mean + to infinitive" means "intend to", and will therefore not be used as an answer to the questions proposed. Instead, "mean + V-ing" can provide a suitable answer to all four questions:

- To be human / Being human **means caring** about others. (Here, "mean" is synonymous with "entail", or "involve", or "imply".)
- To be an American / Being an American **means having** been born in the US. (Here, "mean" is more like "be equivalent to" or "have as meaning".)